# strpos() / stripos() bug or expected behavior?

Tags: preg-match, stripos

I'm trying to check if `<script` or `<link` is in a string.

```
if (stripos($string, '<script') !== FALSE || stripos($string, '<link') !== FALSE)
```

The code above never finds the match unless I take out the <  Do I need to escape that character or something?  I tried `preg_match('~\b<script\b~',$string)` and that failed as well.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: `str_ireplace(array('<script','<link'), array('<replacescript','<replacelink'), $string)` does not work either

Comment: Are you sure you have `<` in your string and not `&lt;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Toto.  I have checked to make sure as I thought of that as well.  <link rel="shortcut icon"